# Use an arraylist from class A in class B

Tags: java, class, arraylist

I need to know how to use an arraylist from a class into another class.
I am using a jFrame, when the user clicks in a button I need to transfer that arraylist to another class (i need to use the data in this class).

What I Have:

Class A (My problem is in the jbuton clicked method):

```
   /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package computadorrbc;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;

/**
 *
 * @author Iago Sestrem Ochôa
 */
public class Tela extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Tela
     */
    public Tela() {
        initComponents();
        ArrayList<String> gabinete = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> processador = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> memoria = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> hd = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> ssd = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> gpu = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> teclado = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> mouse = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> fonte = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> refrigeracao = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> monitor = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> headset = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> motherboard = new ArrayList<String>();
        gabinete.add("Mid Tower");
        gabinete.add("Full Tower");
        processador.add("i7 6700K");
        processador.add("i7 6700");
        processador.add("i5 6600K");
        processador.add("i5 6600");
        memoria.add("HyperX 8GB 1600");
        memoria.add("Vengeance 8GB 1600");
        memoria.add("HyperX 8GB 1866");
        memoria.add("HyperX 8GB 2133");
        hd.add("WD 1TB 7200 RPM");
        hd.add("Seagate 1TB 7200 RPM");
        hd.add("Seagate 2TB 7200 RPM");
        ssd.add("Kingston 120GB");
        ssd.add("Sandisk 120GB");
        ssd.add("Kingston 240GB");
        ssd.add("Sandisk 240GB");
        gpu.add("AMD R9 390");
        gpu.add("AMD R9 Fury");
        gpu.add("AMD R9 390X");
        gpu.add("GTX 980 TI");
        gpu.add("GTX Titan");
        gpu.add("GTX 1080");
        gpu.add("GTX 1070");
        teclado.add("Razer BlackWidow");
        teclado.add("Razer DeathStalker");
        teclado.add("Razer Cynosa");
        mouse.add("Razer Naga");
        mouse.add("Razer Abyssus");
        mouse.add("Razer Krait");
        mouse.add("Razer Deathadder");
        fonte.add("EVGA 1600W");
        fonte.add("Corsair 1500W");
        fonte.add("Coolermaster 1200W");
        fonte.add("SeaSonic 1000W");
        fonte.add("Corsair 860W");
        fonte.add("SeaSonic 520W");
        refrigeracao.add("Água");
        refrigeracao.add("Ar");
        monitor.add("Benq 27p 144Hz");
        monitor.add("Asus 27p 144Hz");
        monitor.add("Asus 27p QuadHD");
        monitor.add("LG 25p FullHD");
        monitor.add("Acer 21,5p FullHD");
        headset.add("Razer Kraken");
        headset.add("Razer TiaMat");
        headset.add("Razer Chiamera");
        headset.add("Razer Manowar");
        headset.add("Logitech G430");
        headset.add("Logitech G933");
        headset.add("Logitech G35");
        motherboard.add("ATX Maximus VIII");
        motherboard.add("ATX ROG STRIX");
        motherboard.add("ATX Sabertooth");
        motherboard.add("ATX 970 PRO");
        motherboard.add("ATX GA 970");
        DefaultListModel model0 = new DefaultListModel();
        for (String s : gabinete) {
            jList1.setModel(model0);
            model0.addElement(s);
        }
        DefaultListModel model1 = new DefaultListModel();
        for (String s : processador) {
            jList2.setModel(model1);
            model1.addElement(s);
        }
        DefaultListModel model2 = new DefaultListModel();
        for (String s : memoria) {
            jList3.setModel(model2);
            model2.addElement(s);
        }
        DefaultListModel model3= new DefaultListModel();
        for (String s : hd) {
            jList4.setModel(model3);
            model3.addElement(s);
        }
        DefaultListModel model4 = new DefaultListModel();
        for (String s : ssd) {
            jList5.setModel(model4);
            model4.addElement(s);
        }
        DefaultListModel model5 = new DefaultListModel();
        for (String s : gpu) {
            jList6.setModel(model5);
            model5.addElement(s);
        }
        DefaultListModel model6 = new DefaultListModel();
        for (String s : teclado) {
            jList7.setModel(model6);
            model6.addElement(s);
        }
        DefaultListModel model7 = new DefaultListModel();
        for (String s : mouse) {
            jList8.setModel(model7);
            model7.addElement(s);
        }
        DefaultListModel model8 = new DefaultListModel();
        for (String s : fonte) {
            jList9.setModel(model8);
            model8.addElement(s);
        }
        DefaultListModel model9 = new DefaultListModel();
        for (String s : refrigeracao) {
            jList10.setModel(model9);
            model9.addElement(s);
        }
        DefaultListModel model10 = new DefaultListModel();
        for (String s : monitor) {
            jList11.setModel(model10);
            model10.addElement(s);
        }
        DefaultListModel model11 = new DefaultListModel();
        for (String s : headset) {
            jList12.setModel(model11);
            model11.addElement(s);
        }
        DefaultListModel model12 = new DefaultListModel();
        for (String s : motherboard) {
            jList13.setModel(model12);
            model12.addElement(s);
        }
    }





    private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
        ArrayList<String> dados = new ArrayList<String>();
        dados.add(jList1.getSelectedValue());
        dados.add(jList2.getSelectedValue());
        dados.add(jList3.getSelectedValue());
        dados.add(jList4.getSelectedValue());
        dados.add(jList5.getSelectedValue());
        dados.add(jList6.getSelectedValue());
        dados.add(jList7.getSelectedValue());
        dados.add(jList8.getSelectedValue());
        dados.add(jList9.getSelectedValue());
        dados.add(jList10.getSelectedValue());
        dados.add(jList11.getSelectedValue());
        dados.add(jList12.getSelectedValue());
        dados.add(jList13.getSelectedValue());
        TelaRBC dados_rbc =  new TelaRBC(dados);
        TelaRBC tela_rbc = new TelaRBC();
        tela_rbc.setVisible(true);
        dispose();
        System.out.print(dados);
    }                                     

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Tela.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Tela.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Tela.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Tela.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Tela().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel10;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel11;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel12;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel13;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel14;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel9;
    private javax.swing.JList<String> jList1;
    private javax.swing.JList<String> jList10;
    private javax.swing.JList<String> jList11;
    private javax.swing.JList<String> jList12;
    private javax.swing.JList<String> jList13;
    private javax.swing.JList<String> jList2;
    private javax.swing.JList<String> jList3;
    private javax.swing.JList<String> jList4;
    private javax.swing.JList<String> jList5;
    private javax.swing.JList<String> jList6;
    private javax.swing.JList<String> jList7;
    private javax.swing.JList<String> jList8;
    private javax.swing.JList<String> jList9;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane10;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane11;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane12;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane13;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane3;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane4;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane5;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane6;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane7;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane8;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane9;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

So I am trying to use the `dados_rbc` in the class B:

```
  package computadorrbc;


public class TelaRBC extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    public TelaRBC() {
        initComponents();
DefaultListModel model4 = new DefaultListModel();
        for (String s : dados_rbc) {
            jList.setModel(model4);
            model4.addElement(s);
    }

    }

public static void main(String args[]) {

java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TelaRBC().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
```

But this is not working, someone knows another method to use the data from the arraylist of class B into the class B?

Comment: Please create and post a valid [mcve]. By the looks of your code, if you do a serious and decent refactoring, you'll make it much easier for you and us to debug and extend, and for us to understand.

Comment: Side recs: you should *not* be adding MouseListeners to JButtons but rather ActionListeners. The one works much better here than the other. Next, you shouldn't be using variables named like jList4,... etc. If you are using that many similar variables, then you should consolidate that into either an array or an ArrayList.

Comment: And you don't want to or need to repeatedly add **the same model** to a JList within your for loop. Add it once, and then update the model alone within the loop.

Comment: Esse método deve ser criado em qual classe @AlmightyR ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ways to solve this immediately come to mind:

1. **Constructor parameters:**
   See [Austin D's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39605092/1253136).
2. **Setting from origin (class A) after instantiation (of class B):**
   In `TelaRBC` (B), create a `Setter` method for the model; and through this method, set the model from class A:

   ```
   //CLASS B
   public void setDados(ArrayList<String> dados) {
       DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
       for (String s : dados) {
           model.addElement(s);
       }
       jList.setModel(model);
   }

   //CLASS A
   private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
       ArrayList<String> dados = new ArrayList<String>();
       dados.add(jList1.getSelectedValue());
       //...
       dados.add(jList13.getSelectedValue());
       TelaRBC tela_rbc = new TelaRBC();

       tela_rbc.setDados(dados); //<<<<<<<<<< The difference.

       tela_rbc.setVisible(true);
       System.out.print(dados);
       dispose();
   }
   ```

---

Extra: In class A, you should be using a `ActionListener` instead of a `MouseClicked`.

Since you're apparently using the NetBeans GUI editor...

1. In the code tab, copy the code from the current event (`Button1MouseClicked()`).
2. In the visual tab, select `jButton1`.
3. On the properties window, go to the `Events` tab, and delete the current `MouseClicked` event.
4. Go to the `ActionPerformed` event (top), add it, and past the code to it.

At the end, you should have no `jButton1MouseClicked()` method, and instead have this:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    //... (code that was previously in the 'MouseClicked' method)
}
```

Comment: Ok, I understood your solution, but now, how i print the arraylist `dados` in the class B, i need to use the arraylist in class B.

Comment: For example: I want to print the arraylist `dados` from the class A in the initcomponents of the class B.

Comment: @Mutante We don't know how you're using it, or how you will use it, in class B; so it's impossible to answer that question any further than what's basically what you've already done: `System.out.print(dados);` or in this case `System.out.println(jList.getModel().toString())` --- Also, anything further is outside the scope of this current question, and would make the current question *too broad* if edited-in here. So you should try to look for existing Q&As. and if you don't find any that helps you, then you can post it as a new question. =)

Comment: @Mutante You should probably avoid doing it inside `initcomponents`; otherwise you would be putting something that is not an *initialization* within a method that is specific to doing initialization, thus breaking it's purpose and consistency. --- You probably want to do it right after it's called, *in the **constructor***, instead. However, you won't be able to do that appropriately with my method, as the initialization (constructor) and setting the `dados` are done separately at different times; and `dados` would not and could not be set by the time the contructor runs... (continues)

Comment: @Mutante However, in the first place, that's probably not how you want to use `dados` in the first place; and, even for using it that way for testing purposes, you could easily implement Austin's solution while maintaining the `Setter` method, by simply calling the setter from the constructor: `public TelaRBC(ArrayList<String> dados){ initComponents(); this.setDados(dados); }` --- Since you seem to be having difficulty with multiple things, if you need me to, I can help you with a full review of your project/code. Just post it to GitHub if possible (and link here), or call me on chat. =)

Answer (score 3):

In the constructor for `TelaRBC` save the `ArrayList` parameter to a field, e.g.

```
public class TelaRBC {

    private ArrayList<String> dadosList; //the ArrayList of selected values

    public TelaRBC(ArrayList<String> theList){ 
        this.dadosList = theList;
        //... remainder of the constructor omitted
    }
    //.. remainder of the TelaRBC class implementation omitted
}
```

Then add a method like `getArrayList` to the `TelaRBC` class, e.g.:

```
public ArrayList<String> getArrayList(){ return this.dadosList;}
```

Comment: `dados_rbc` it's not a class. How can I do this? Sorry, I am new in Java.

Comment: @Mutante Sorry, corrected to the `TelaRBC` class ;)

Comment: Ok, I will update my post with my entire code, I am not understanding this.